# Trying to use a variable as an index but it won't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

In Python I'm trying to make it so that `'number'` points to the exact same number in the list as `x` (this probably sounds stupid but its a simplified version of what I'm trying to accomplish).

But, for some reason the index assumes `x` is still 1 instead of 2 (which it is after `x += 1`)

```
list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

x = 1

number = list[x]

print(number)
x += 1

print(number)
print(x)
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I'm pretty new to all of this.

I expect an output of `1 2 2` but I got `1 1 2`

Comment: Side-note: Naming your variable `list` is a *terrible* idea, insofar as it cuts off access to the `list` constructor in that scope. Better hope you don't need to convert anything to a `list` soon... (there are workarounds, but as a rule, don't use built-in names as your own variable names). `lst` is commonly used for anonymous `list`s to avoid this problem (`l` being disfavored because it's hard to tell `l`, `I` and `1` apart at a glance in many fonts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, reassigning `x` will not automatically reassign `number`.

In general, having two variables that need to be reassigned at the same time is an easy way to confuse yourself -- if you ever forget to update one after updating the other, you're likely to have a bug in your program, and then you need to hunt all over the place to figure out at what point the two drifted apart.

A better approach is usually to have a single value (a single "source of truth") and then use a function that will automatically calculate the associated value from it.  In an OOP context you'd frequently do this by defining a `@property`, but you can also do it with a plain old function:

```
numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

x = 1
def number():
    return numbers[x]

print(number())
x += 1

print(number())
print(x)
```

prints:

```
1
2
2
```

Note that since `number` is a function, you need to call it (i.e. `number()`) to get the desired value.  Calling the function is what causes `numbers[x]` to be re-evaluated, giving you the updated value for `number`.

Answer (score 1):

In this, we do increment the value of x, but the variable `number` still have 1 in it. We have to reassign it again to get the value 2.

Code :

```py
listOfNumbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

value = 1

matchingNumber = listOfNumbers[value]

print(matchingNumber)
value += 1
matchingNumber = listOfNumbers[value]
print(matchingNumber)
print(value)
```

Output :

```
1
2
2
```

NB: Please do not use `list` as a variable name, because it overshadows the built-in name `list`.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  # do not use list as a variable name

x = 1

number = lst[x]   # number got the value 1 from lst[1]

print(number)

x += 1           # x is incremented by 1

number = lst[x]  # add this line to change number, now it is lst[2]

print(number)
print(x)

#output
1
2
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `x` after assigning `number` won't change `number`. For the intended result, you would have to reassign `number` after the `x` change:

```
list_num = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] 
x = 1
number = list_num[x] 
print(number) 
x += 1 
number = list_num[x]
print(number) 
print(x)
```

EDIT: you should not use `list` as a variable name

Answer (score 0):

here is the code:

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

x = 1

number = lst[x]  # Assign the value at index 1 (1) to number
print(number)  # Output: 1

x += 1  # Increment the value of x by 1

number = lst[x]  # Reassign number with the updated value at index 2 (2)
print(number)  # Output: 2

print(x)  # Output: 2 (x has been incremented)
```